# MySQL ORDER BY total rows of user in another table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Suppose, I want to show a list of users ordering by the most number of messages they have sent.

I have 2 tables: `Users` and `Messages`

I have 10 users

User A sent 20 messages (have 20 rows in Messages table)

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user='A'


User B sent 17 msgs    
User C sent 19    
User D sent 13
```

and so on.

I want to a query that will list Users in order of their total messages sent. Like:

```
1. A (20 msgs)
2. C (19 msgs)
3. B (17 msgs)
4. D (13 msgs)
```

I tried hard but I can't find any query to execute this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not needlessly duplicate your questions, this possible duplicate of [MySQL ORDER BY highest number of rows in another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732723/mysql-order-by-highest-number-of-rows-in-another-table) has been posted by yourself at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT user, COUNT(*) FROM messages GROUP BY user ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

Comment: Was typing an answer and boom this appeared. No need to continue, that's your answer.

Comment: Yea, I hate it when that happens ;)

Comment: It is giving only one row while using the above query. The expected behavior is it should get all results order by count(*)

Comment: No, it doesn't. You are doing something wrong, or perhaps your data has only one value for `user`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the names join users table,

```
select user_name, count(*) from users inner join messages m on users.userid=m.messageid group by userid order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort using an `alias`:

```
SELECT user, COUNT(1) as cnt
FROM Messages 
GROUP BY user 
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

or `position`:

```
SELECT user, COUNT(1) as cnt
FROM Messages 
GROUP BY user 
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```