# MySQL ORDER BY highest number of rows in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL ORDER BY total rows of user in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730493/mysql-order-by-total-rows-of-user-in-another-table)

I have 5 users (on table `users`):

```
User ID (uid) | User Name (uname)
-----------------------------------
1               Fallon
2               Jeremy
3               Matt
4               Peter
5               John
```

- Fallon (uid 1) has logged in 35 times so far.
- Jeremy logged in 32 times.
- Matt logged in 57 times.
- Peter logged in 43 times.
- John logged in 23 times.

Log details are stored in another table (`logs`):

```
Log ID (logid) - User ID (uid)
```

Now I want to represent a list of users in order of most logged times. The user who logged in the most will be at the top, second most logged user will be the second. Like:

1. Matt logged in 57 times.
2. Peter logged in 43 times.
3. Fallon logged in 35 times.
4. Jeremy logged in 32 times.
5. John logged in 23 times.

Because Logs are stored in one table and User details in another. How can I, What queries should I, use to make a list like the above. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a simple query involving a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT users.uid, users.uname, COUNT(logs.logid) AS logins 
  FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN logs ON logs.uid=users.uid 
  GROUP BY users.uid
  ORDER BY logins DESC
```

Comment: @tadman . . . Please add the group by so your answer can be upvoted.  Not only were your first, but you are the only answer that uses proper join syntax.

Comment: Done! Didn't realize I'd missed that.

Comment: Thanks. it worked. I didnt think of GROUP BY for which my codes weren't working. Thanks a lot bro. :)

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but I believe this should work:

```
SELECT u.`uid`, u.`uname`, COUNT( l.`logid` ) AS count 
FROM `users` AS u, `logs` AS l 
WHERE u.`uid` = l.`uid` 
GROUP BY l.`uid` 
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT users.uid, users.uname, COUNT(logs.logid) as logins 
  FROM users, logs 
  where  logs.uid=users.uid 
  GROUP BY logs.uid
  ORDER BY logins DESC
```